# How to make good pagenumbering in LaTeX for academic work?

Tags: page-numbering

It would be nice, if you would help me make som beautiful pagenumbering. And with beautiful I mean the pagenumbering on the images i posted. And I've anyone of you have some pagenumbering you prefer or could be interesting here, it would be nice if you would post it here, so beginners like me can choose their pagenumbering for their latex documents.

I have nearly the same pagenumbering layout like that on the first picture, but the pagnumbering have to be central, because otherwise the standard pagenumbering will show up again.

Kind regards.

[image: Pagenumbering 1]
[image: Pagenumbering 2]

Minimal exampel:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}%generelt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%europæisk skrifttegn
\usepackage[danish]{babel}%dansk

\usepackage{amsmath}%matematik
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}%billedimplementering
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%størrelsesforhold
\usepackage{cleveref}%refere med \cref og \cpageref

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%URL
\hypersetup{hidelinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\usepackage{caption}%figurtekster
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=it,labelfont=it}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%skrifttype


\usepackage{chemfig}%kemi
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%overskrifter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}%sideantal

\thispagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}%dokumentbegyndelse
\begingroup
    \noindent
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
        \hline
        Received:            & Approved:  \cr
                             & Date:      \cr
                             & Signature: \cr
        (for the instructor) &            \cr
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
\bigskip
\begingroup
    \centering
    \obeylines
    \scshape
    \lsstyle
   \normalsize MY LESSON
    \vspace{0.01ex}
    \Huge Aflevering 3
 \vspace{0.1ex}
    \normalsize MY NAME \\{\small STUDENTNUMBER} \linebreak
   \hspace{1ex}    
    \begin{normalsize}
    Institute for ...........
    \end{normalsize}
    \large MY UNIVERSITY
   {\normalsize  \today}
\endgroup

\clearpage

\pagebreak
\twocolumn
\rhead{\scshape{\today}}
\lhead{\scshape{MY NAME}}

\cfoot{\scshape{Side \thepage \ af \pageref{LastPage}}}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
```

Comment: You can build pretty much any pagenumbering. Can you make a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231)?

Comment: As the old saying goes, beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Please be a bit more specific as to what you consider to be "beautiful page numbering".

Comment: Well… that's not really *minimal*.

Comment: By the way, you can clear all the headers and footers with `\fancyhf{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [pageslts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) can give you of 'Page n of m' style for page numbers. Here is one way to set it up with fancyhdr:

```
\usepackage{pageslts}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage{} of \lastpageref*{VeryLastPage}}
```

The starred version of the command prevents the number of the last page from being a link to the last page, which I find visually ugly when links are coloured.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}%generelt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%europæisk skrifttegn
\usepackage[danish]{babel}%dansk

\usepackage{amsmath}%matematik
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}%billedimplementering
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%størrelsesforhold
\usepackage{cleveref}%refere med \cref og \cpageref

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%URL
\hypersetup{hidelinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\usepackage{caption}%figurtekster
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=it,labelfont=it}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%skrifttype


\usepackage{chemfig}%kemi
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%overskrifter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}%sideantal

\thispagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}%dokumentbegyndelse
\begingroup
    \noindent
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
        \hline
        Received:            & Approved:  \cr
                             & Date:      \cr
                             & Signature: \cr
        (for the instructor) &            \cr
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
\bigskip
\begingroup
    \centering
    \obeylines
    \scshape
    \lsstyle
   \normalsize MY LESSON
    \vspace{0.01ex}
    \Huge Aflevering 3
 \vspace{0.1ex}
    \normalsize MY NAME \\{\small STUDENTNUMBER} \linebreak
   \hspace{1ex}
    \begin{normalsize}
    Institute for ...........
    \end{normalsize}
    \large MY UNIVERSITY
   {\normalsize  \today}
\endgroup

\clearpage

\pagebreak
\twocolumn
\rhead{\scshape{\today}}
\lhead{\scshape{MY NAME}}

\cfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hrulefill\kern-0.6ex\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\Bigl[$\makebox[2em][c]{\thepage}$\Bigr]$}\kern-0.5ex\hrulefill}}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another example:

```
\cfoot{$\overset{\textcolor{olive}{\resizebox{!}{0.65em}{${\cdots}$}}}{\makebox[2em][c]{\thepage}}$}
```

[image]